# How to retrieve content based chapter and paragraph from the word file using open xml and c#4.0?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I am using c# and open xml sdk 2.0 for accessing Word file.

For that, now i want to retrieve a chapter and paragraph based on the given text.

If the chapter contains my text then retrieve the paragraph containing that text...

```
FOR EXAMPLE: Given Word is: Chapter 1 - Events
```

Retrieve the chapter and paragraphs that containing the word `"Chapter 1 - Events"`

I want to search the given word on the Word file.

If any matches found, then i want to display that methods and insert into database according with this schema

[image]

If matches not found, no need to get the paragraph.

How i do?

*code-behind* (now the return on visual studio debug is empty)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

public partial class Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string file = @"C:\Users\file.docx";

            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(file, true))
            {
                Body body = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

                string paras = "";

                foreach (Paragraph p in wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Paragraph>().Where<Paragraph>(p => p.InnerText.Contains("Chapter [0-9]{1;} ")))
                {
                    paras += p.InnerText + "<br/>";
                }

                Response.Write(paras);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*file.docx*

```
Chapter 1 - Events
 - alert or disservices
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
….
….
- significant activities
Phasellus dui nunc, rutrum vitae dictum eleifend, ullamcorper hendrerit sem
….
….

Chapter 2 – Safety
- near miss
Praesent venenatis convallis nunc, quis ultrices massa
….
….
- security checks
Phasellus mollis dapibus porta. Phasellus ac tristique dui
….
….

Chapter 3 – Training
- environment
Nunc hendrerit scelerisque mauris vel eleifend
….
….
- upkeep
Mauris id elit nec nisl laoreet posuere. Donec ac molestie sem
….
….
```

*database table*

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `chapters`;
CREATE TABLE `chapters` (
  `chapter` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `subheading` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `contents` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `sID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```